# Custom component for uploading files is sharing instance and not working as expected

Tags: html, angular, input

In my application I have some modules which should have the possibility to upload images.

I created a child component for handling the image uploading, for easy reuse. 
The problem is when I upload image from one of the child components it is always displayed in the first component instance.

I have replicated the issue here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6ug9f6

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your file inputs have the same `id`, so when you click the second `label`, it refers back to the first `input`. Try generating a dynamic `id` for each `input` and that should do the trick.

Comment: Correct, and solved by passing an unique id in as a property to the child. Thanks.